# Crate that allows my application to launch a new console screen

Tags: rust

I have a Rust application that runs from a console.  When run I want the application to run a thread that opens a 'new console' window and prints text to that window.

Is there a crate or configuration anyone can suggest for launching a second (and maybe third and fourth) Terminal screen?

Comment: This will be very plateforme-specific. Eg. Linux doesn’t have a concept of terminal window, a program could just as well be running in a tty, or a pipe, or be called from another program with its output captured, etc. Plus, different distributions have different terminal emulators, how would you know which one to start?

Comment: Your question is off topic because you ask recommandation, and also unclear as you didn't specify what operating system you are using.

Answer (score 1):

That's very platform specific.  You could start a new process, use x on Linux in process, use Wayland on Linux in process, use Win32 API on Windows, (list goes on)

You also might consider any ui frameworks etc for rust (of which there are few)

Creating a new process of terminal emulator on the system and writing to it's std in while launching cat in it is probably your best bet https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html

I hope this helps